# Initialize data in Vue Component from vuex api request

Tags: vue.js, vuex

What is the simplest way to initialize data in a Vue component from an async api call in a vuex store. The component mounts before the data is available.

Consider:

```
export default {
data () {
  return {
    loanAmount: 300000,
    thirtyFixedAPR: null,
    fifteenFixedAPR: null,
    fiveArmAPR: null
  }
},
methods: {
  fetchRates () {
    this.thirtyFixedAPR = this.$store.state.rates.thirtyFixed.apr
    this.fifteenFixedAPR = this.$store.state.rates.fifteenFixed.apr
    this.fiveArmAPR = this.$store.state.rates.fiveArm.apr
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.fetchRates()
}}
```

I want to call the fetchRates method once after the api call in the vuex store is finished. I'd use a computed property but I only want to initialize the data, not watch it. I've experimented with a few workarounds using watchers that don't seem very elegant and I have a feeling there is a simpler answer to this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried doing it in the "created" method instead of mount()?

Comment: Yes. No combination of lifestyle hooks seems to work.

Comment: what if you put in a delay, so inside mounted() make the component wait a few seconds before calling vuex for data?

Comment: That probably is the simplest solution I just tend to stay away from delays as much as possible.

Comment: Yea I agree. What about having all those properties returned by 1 function and that function returns a promise, then u give the promise a callback and extract your data when network call is complete.

Comment: where is your api request?? Is it inside your vuex actions??

Comment: It would be better to make a `getter` instead of fetching from `state`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subscribe in Vuex.

Basically;

```
const myMutationListener = this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  if (mutation.type === 'MY_MUTATION_INSIDE_VUEX'){
   this.parameter1 = mutation.payload.parameter1
   this.parameter2 = mutation.payload.parameter2
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `getter` for your vuex store then retrieve your data from it from your page computed.

**Store ===> getters**

```
 getters: {
    thirtyFixedAPR: (state) => state.rates.thirtyFixed.apr,
    fifteenFixedAPR : (state) => state.rates.fifteenFixed.apr,
    fiveArmAPR: (state) => state.rates.fiveArm.apr,
}
```

**page.vue**

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        thirtyFixedAPR: "thirtyFixedAPR",
        fifteenFixedAPR : "fifteenFixedAPR",
        fiveArmAPR: "fiveArmAPR"
    }),
},
```

Hope this helps you out.